# Calling useNavigate('url') inside layer.click() is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, geojson, react-leaflet

In this project, I'm using react leaflet to show a map which generated by GEOJSON features object. I just to go to a dynamic country route when clicking on each of the country layer.

```
const geoJsonRef = useRef();
useEffect(()=>{
    geoJsonRef.current.getLayers().map((layer)=>{
        layer.on({
            click : ()=>{
                useNavigate( 'go/to/country' ); // here is the error occurs
            }
        });
    });
}, [state]);
return(
    <MapContainer style={containerStyle} center={[10, 0]} zoom={2} minZoom={2.4} maxZoom={10}>
        <GeoJSON style={contryStyle} data={features} onEachFeature={onEachCountry} ref={geoJsonRef} />
    </MapContainer>
);
```

Error:

```
React Hook "useNavigate" is called in function "click" that is neither a React
function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names
must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use" 
react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

From this error I can understand that, it is incorrect way of using useNavigate(). The same I got when attaching the click handler in the `onEachCountry` function.
I just need to know the correct way click handler to give the route.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React hooks can ***only*** be called from React function components or custom hooks, they cannot be called in callbacks, conditions, and loops as this breaks the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

Call the `useNavigate` hook first in the component body to return the `navigate` function, *then* call `navigate` in any callback/hook/etc...

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
  geoJsonRef
    .current
    .getLayers()
    .map((layer) => {
      layer.on({
        click: () => {
          navigate('go/to/country');
        }
      });
  });
}, [state]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Drew. I forget the use of these Hooks.
Could you please suggest a best practice and globally used coding standard reference for React applications?